# A way to send data from string to variable every 200 postions -For loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop, replace

I have a variable 'strs' as a string with a total text of 10,000 count. I would like the data from this variable to be passed every 200 count to another variable that would pass this data to the API command.
My below code does not work.

```
pojazd = []
with requests.Session() as sesja:
    sesja.headers.update(headers)
    print(len(strs))
    s11 = ""
    s12 = ""
    s1 = ""
    s2 = ""
    val = 200
    for i,value in enumerate(strs):
        val2 = val+200
        if i < val:
            s11+=value
            s1 = str('https://api.allegro.pl/sale/compatible-products?type=CAR&phrase="{}"').format(s11)
            print(s1)
            info = [s1]
            for i in tqdm(info):
                response = sesja.get(i)
                print(response.content)
                wyswietl = response.json()
                for p in wyswietl['compatibleProducts']:
                    t = str(p['id'])
                    pojazd.append({ 'id': t, 'type': 'ID'})
        elif i >val and i <val2:
            s12+=value
            s2 = str('https://api.allegro.pl/sale/compatible-products?type=CAR&phrase="{}"').format(s12)
            print(s1)
            print(s2)
            info = [s2]
            for i in tqdm(info):
                response = sesja.get(i)
                print(response.content)
                wyswietl = response.json()
                for p in wyswietl['compatibleProducts']:
                    t = str(p['id'])
                    pojazd.append({ 'id': t, 'type': 'ID'})
        else:
            val+=200
```

Comment: You may use enumerate, yield and string slicing.

Comment: While I do not understand what you are asking, two of the branches of the conditional statement you present look entirely too similar: Avoid "code duplication".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const = 200
round = 1
strs = range(0,10001)

def pass_variable(v,r):
    print(v,r)

for i,value in enumerate(strs): 
   if i <= const*round:
      pass
   else:
       round = round+1
   pass_variable(value, round)
```

you can use round for split variable.

Comment: (Try this with an iterable `strs` and report.)

Comment: I edited new code already, This code can copy and test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator function and string slicing:

```
def chunk_wise(string, length=200):
    start, chunknumber = [0, 1]
    for idx, _ in enumerate(string):
        if idx == chunknumber * length:
            yield string[start:idx]
            start = idx
            chunknumber += 1

    rest = len(string) - start
    if rest:
        yield string[start:]


mystring = "abcde123456"

for part in chunk_wise(mystring, 5):
    print(part)
```

Which would yield with these parameters:

```
abcde
12345
6
```